# Problem with freeing memory of linked lists

Tags: c, malloc

I am trying to write a function that will free all the nodes (buckets) of a linked list. When I try to run the following code, I get a malloc error though I am unsure why as I think I am freeing correctly. Any insights will be greatly appreciated thanks.

```
typedef struct bucket bucket;
struct bucket {
  char *string;
  unsigned long int hash;
  bucket *next;
};

void bucket_free(bucket *b)
{
  if(b == NULL){
    free(b);
  }
  else{
    free(b->string);
    bucket_free(b->next);
    free(b);
  }
}
```

When I run this code, I get:

```
a.out(58188,0x7fff943f7380) malloc: *** error for object 0x106ec4fa6: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: if the pointer is `NULL` it has not been allocated by you

Comment: Don't `free` the pointer which is `NULL`. It is not allocated any memory.

Comment: Calling `free` with NULL is okay. `free` takes care of that. The problem is somewhere else. How did you `malloc`-ed the structure?

Comment: probably you share some `x->string` and try to free the string 2 times.  anyway, you need to paste the code of initialization of your list, otherwise it does not reproduce.

Comment: My cheap hazy glass stone pitiful excuse for a crystal ball tells me you're not terminating your linked list correctly, ultimately freeing a value that is an indeterminate pointer. I further dare under penalty of folly to suggest your hash table these things are managed in is never primed with nulls, thereby causing the aforementioned condition. Now, how about we dispense with the guesses and you provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem so we can say with conviction what the *real* problem is.

Comment: If (as I strongly suspect) you're on macOS (or perhaps a BSD system), then you can set `export MallocScribble="${MallocScribble:-1}" ; export MallocCheckHeapStart="${MallocCheckHeapStart:-1}"; export MallocCheckHeapEach="${MallocCheckHeapEach:-1}"; export MallocCheckHeapAbort="${MallocCheckHeapAbort:-1}"; export MallocErrorAbort="${MallocErrorAbort:-1}"` in the environment before you run your program to get some abuses of memory reported better. Or use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) if you use an old enough [sic!] version of macOS or a non-macOS machine. I use a script for this.